# Unable to init with google repo tool using local identity

Tags: python, git, identity, repo

trying to init project tree using repo tool but having a failure on assigning local identity:

`repo init -u git@github.com:XXX.git -b repo-rocko --config-name`

returns:

`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/projects/repo.test/.repo/repo/main.py", line 531, in <module>
    _Main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/user/projects/repo.test/.repo/repo/main.py", line 507, in _Main
    result = repo._Run(argv) or 0
  File "/home/user/projects/repo.test/.repo/repo/main.py", line 180, in _Run
    result = cmd.Execute(copts, cargs)
  File "/home/user/projects/repo.test/.repo/repo/subcmds/init.py", line 404, in Execute
    self._ConfigureUser()
  File "/home/user/projects/repo.test/.repo/repo/subcmds/init.py", line 298, in _ConfigureUser
    name  = self._Prompt('Your Name', mp.UserName)
  File "/home/user/projects/repo.test/.repo/repo/project.py", line 784, in UserName
    self._LoadUserIdentity()
  File "/home/user/projects/repo.test/.repo/repo/project.py", line 797, in _LoadUserIdentity
    u = self.bare_git.var('GIT_COMMITTER_IDENT')
  File "/home/user/projects/repo.test/.repo/repo/project.py", line 2747, in runner
    (self._project.name, name, p.stderr))
error.GitError: manifests var: 
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
```

`

but when trying to use git to config identity:

`git config user.name "Test test"`

having a failure:

`fatal: not in a git directory`

and GLOBAL setting is NOT an option for this case because according to the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) will store identity in `~/.gitconfig` file rather than the repository `.git/config` and will compromise other repo runs on other projects in other folders.

Comment: to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

Answer (score 2):

the google `repo` script option `--config-name` is broken (not working as supposed to be) as for the moment on version:

`

```
repo version v1.12.37
       (from https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo)
repo launcher version 1.23
       (from /usr/bin/repo)
git version 2.14.1
Python 2.7.14 (default, Sep 23 2017, 22:06:14) 
[GCC 7.2.0]
```

`

but there is a work-around:

immediately after `repo init` command but before following `repo sync` command to modify already existing file (repo will generate this file automatically):

`.repo/manifests.git/config`

by adding identity as following lines to the bottom of the file:

`

```
[user]
        email = user@yourdomain.com
        name = User Name
```

`